# Programmatically draw and show / copy / save an image

Tags: wpf, vb.net, bitmap

I'd like to draw an image (like a bar code) pixel-by-pixel in a Visual Basic .NET WPF Application and …

1. show the image in my UI
2. copy it to the clipboard
3. save it as a .BMP-File.

It should also be possible to add Paint-like editing features later.

What is a good approach?

`System.Drawing.Bitmap` works internally, but the only way I could show it is to convert it to an `ImageSource` and show it inside an `Image` control. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) might help, it already is an `ImageSource`. Check out the documentation for some usage examples. I have not used this for a long time so i cannot help you with it, possibly searches on this site may turn up some useful info as well.

As `WriteableBitmap` is a `BitmapSource` you can just use [`Clipboard.SetImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard.setimage.aspx) to copy it.

To save images you can in general use a subclass ob [`BitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) (also see doc for usage; you probably want to use the `BmpBitmapEncoder`).